# Loose and missing struts(?) in attic roof

Tags: roof, attic

There appears to be loose (3 of them) and missing struts - two of the struts are lying on the ceiling.
[image: see attached image]Should I get them fixed quickly? We live in NJ where there is snow load on the roof.

Comment: It's quite common to see scrap bits of wood in attic crawl spaces.  Can you highlight the loose pieces, the ones lying on the floor, and where you think they belong?  Within the area that is sufficiently lit in the photo it's hard to see what you mean.   IT's possible the loose and missing pieces were used temporarily during construction and left behind.

Comment: How old is the house? If you stand out in the street, can you see any dips or humps in the roof?

Comment: About three of the boards are loose on the top (nails seems to have come off).  The gaps (hard to see) in the lines of struts towards the back has the boards on the ceiling. it appears like they fell off since I can see the nails sticking out on the top and bottom. The roof was replaced in 2019 and everything was inspected as well. Unsure if the struts fell off after or the inspector didn’t bother to check the attic. The house was built in 1972.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s a couple of ways to approach this.

(But first, a bit of rambling: this is a stick-built roof, with sturdy looking rafters, so from afar, this doesn’t look like it needs a ton of work. It also, apparently, hasn’t demonstrated any major issues in 50-ish years. If your roofers had noticed anything obvious, it would have been in their economic interest to mention it in 2019.)

So, answer 1 is to get a general contractor or a structural engineer up there to assess and recommend remediation. Costly and good.

Answer 2 is to arm yourself with a battery drill and impact driver, a tapered #8 countersink, a pound of 3” deck screws, a hammer, a headlight and maybe a hard hat. Hammer the loose nails snug. Put at least 2 screws at every connection that was loose. (Use the countersink because the wood is old and prone to cracking/splitting near the ends.) Inexpensive and satisfying.

If you choose option 2 and find it to be quirky or not as straightforward as it seemed, ask again… maybe option 1 is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much!!